# Import a very long list of string in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, import

I have a very, very long list of words, each on a new line. Like so:

```
abactor
abaculi
abaculus
abacus
abacuses
abada
...
...
...
zythum
zyzzyva
zyzzyvas
```

I want to import all these words in a MySql Database. What would be the most effective method to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Create the table to store  the data:

```
create table words
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  word varchar(255),
  index(word)
);
```

2 Use the `load data` command to insert your text file in table.

```
load data local infile '/tmp/words.txt' into table words(word);
```

`'/tmp/words.txt'` is your file.

3 Check if everything is ok:

```
select * from words limit 9;
+----+----------+
| id | word     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | abactor  |
|  2 | abaculi  |
|  3 | abaculus |
|  4 | abacus   |
|  5 | abacuses |
|  6 | abada    |
|  7 | zythum   |
|  8 | zyzzyva  |
|  9 | zyzzyvas |
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

First you did not specify the language you are working with. But anyway I'm going to assume you have already created a database and table, and set up connection between your MySQL and programming language. Using Java as an example.

1. Open the text file containing the list of words
2. Using the while loop insert the words into the database

### code:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/yourdatabase";
String user = "username";
String password = "password";

// Load the Connector/J driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
// Establish connection to MySQL
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

FileReader fr = new FileReader("C://Documents/words.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

String word = null;

while((word=br.readLine())!=null){
   stmt.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (word_column) VALUES ("+word+")");
}
br.close()
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```